# Laravel RelationShip (join with where)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need help with Laravel 5 (using Eloquent)

I have 2 tables...

Model Driver
drivers

- id
- company

Model DriverOnline
drivers_online

- id
- name
- driver_id

I need to search for a result on (company=1 and driver_id=driver.id).

Please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to only fetch `Driver` based on a condition, you can just do this:

```
Driver::with('online')->where('company', 1)->get();
```

If the clause is on the relationship, use `with` and specify a query on that.

```
$company = 1;
$drivers = Driver::with(['online' => function($query) use ($company)
{
    $query->where('company', $company);
}]);
```

See "Eager Load Constraints":
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Take note of my `use`. This allows you to include variables from the scope into your Closure instance.

And be aware, if you use  either solution, you must set up a relationship. Consult the link I shared with more information on that.

Edit: As per our conversation.

```
$drivers = Driver::where('company_id','=',1)
    ->with('driversOnline')
    ->whereHas('driversOnline', function($query) {
        $query->where('online','=',1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: ```
$drivers = Driver::with(['driversOnline' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('online','=',1);
        }])->where('company_id','=',1)->get();
```

Comment: but get me all on driver

Comment: If you want to only select online Drivers, you should invert it. `DriverOnline::with('driver')->where('online', true)->get();`

Comment: That is a one-to-one relationship. You would access your driver by doing `$online->driver`.

Comment: I need to work with the first condition company_id table = 1 , and the second foreign key online = 1

Comment: I unerstand now, I think. You only want drivers who are online and who belong to a specific company. I have updated my answer to include `whereHas`, which filters results that do not match a relationship restraint. Please try that.

Comment: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, none given, called in F:\web\lara.loc\app\Http\Controllers\AdminCompanyController.php on line 31